# constraint in Django: exactly 1 of 2 foreign keys has to be null

Tags: django, foreign-keys, constraints

I'd like to allow null on two foreign key fields.

But the two fields should not be null at the same time.
Actually, exactly one has to be set at any time.

How can I express this?

The two tables the foreign keys reference are not the same.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928692/how-to-express-a-one-to-many-relationship-in-django

Comment: This is frequently a design anti-pattern for subtyping. 
[How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3579079/3404097)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't achive this by adding something on model fields. You will have to put this logic in your `save()`.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    fk1 = models.ForeignKey(Some, null=True)
    fk2 = models.ForeignKey(Other, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if not fk1 and not fk2:
           raise Exception("You can't leave both fields as null")
       super(self, MyModel).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Shouldn't validation be done in the `clean` method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method :

```
Class TestModel(models.Model):
   forgein_key_1 = models.ForeignKey(YourModel)
   forgein_key_2 = models.ForeignKey(YourOtherModel)
```

and override the save method as:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kargs):
        if not (self.forgein_key_1 or self.forgein_key_2):
          raise Exception("Your Custom Exception Message here")
        super(self, TestModel).save(*args, **kargs)
```

Comment: Probably an explanation would help as well.