# How to add "+" button in Django Admin when using one-to-many relationship if that model have ForeignKey?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

This question is extension of [Better Django UI for one to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299692/better-django-ui-for-one-to-many-relationship).

**modles.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Dude(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=100, unique=True)

    def phones(self):
        # use reverse relation to get a list ofall recorded numbers
        phone_numbers = self.phonenumber_set.values_list('number', flat=True)  
        phone_count   = self.phonenumber_set.count()
        return "This user have %s numbers recorded: %s" % (phone_count, ', '.join(phone_numbers))

    def __unicode__(self):
            return u"%s" % self.name

class PhoneType(models.Model):
    name   = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=100, unique=True)

class PhoneNumber(models.Model):
    dude   = models.ForeignKey(Dude)
    number = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=100, unique=True)
    type   = models.ForeignKey(PhoneType)
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.

from TestingDjango.apps.one_to_many.models \
import Dude, PhoneNumber

class PhoneNumberInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PhoneNumber
    extra = 1

class DudeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
    list_display  = ('name', 'phones')
    inlines = [ PhoneNumberInline, ]

class PhoneNumberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
    list_display  = ('dude', 'number')

admin.site.register(Dude, DudeAdmin)
```

When I add new Dude I can only select existing PhoneType. There is no "+" button like for other ForeignKey fields. I suspect that that is duo to this one-to-many relationship. So how to add "+" button for PhoneType ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to register PhoneNumberAdmin to make it accessible to Django's admin, then it will give you the '+' option to add more.

insert

```
admin.site.register(PhoneNumber, PhoneNumberAdmin)
```

at the bottom of the file