# OneToMany relationship in Django with one model locked

Tags: django

I know what ForeignKeys and OneToOneFields are, as well as ManyToManyField, how they work, and when to use them. However, I am working with a project, whose *Many* part of the relation cannot be modified. So, suppose [I want to let a user have many phone numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6929224/1558430), I would normally do this:

```
# my_app/models.py
from django.db import models
class User(Model):
    ...

class PhoneNumber(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

The problem I have is that my `PhoneNumber` model equivalent is from a third-party package, already populated with records, and not subclassed in my own app. That is

```
# third_party_django_package/models.py
from django.db import models
class PhoneNumber(models.Model):
    # This cannot change

# my_app/models.py
from django.db import models
from third_party_django_package.models import PhoneNumber
class User(Model):
    # These do not work -- a user can have more than one phone number
    phone_number = models.ForeignKey(PhoneNumber)
    phone_number = models.OneToOneField(PhoneNumber)

    # This is close, but I want a phone number to belong to only one User
    phone_numbers = models.ManyToManyField(PhoneNumber, related_name=...)

    def clean(self):
        # Validating the M2M relation costs extra queries, is slow, and 
        # is prone to race conditions
```

This is all pseudocode.

Without using [yet another third-party package](https://github.com/adsworth/django-onetomany) that accesses Django's internal members, which makes the project even less forwards-compatible, what options do I have left to achieve a proper OneToManyField with the correct schema-level constraints?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create another intermediate model, then make phone number OneToOneField to that model, then in that model you define User as ForeignKey.

```
class UserPhoneNumber(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.OneToOneField(PhoneNumber)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

It's a little cumbersome, but at least it achieves what you need.

**Edit:**

As @Daniel said, it's possible to do this using m2m relationship with `through` model, with `unique_together` on the fields:

```
class User(Model):
    phone_numbers = models.ManyToManyField(PhoneNumber, through=UserPhoneNumber)

class UserPhoneNumber(Model):
    phone_number = models.ForeignKey(PhoneNumber)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('phone_number', 'user')
```

This will make your life easier if you want to look up on user's phone numbers by doing `numbers = user.phone_numbers.all()`.

Comment: I don't think you can do better than this, or an equivalent model inheritance setup.

Comment: Aha, this worked in my head! Agreed about everything you said, including the cumbersome part.

Comment: You might actually be able to define this as the through table of an M2M from User to PhoneNumber, in which case it becomes significantly less cumbersome.

Comment: Doesn't the M2M implementation still allow for the possibility of a phone number belonging to more than one user, which the OP notes in pseudocode as undesirable? The `unique_together` constraint prevents the same phone number from being recorded multiple times, but doesn't prevent different users from sharing one.

Comment: Yeah, I asked the question after realising an M2M (with `through` or otherwise) is not possible. The original answer is still better than any other option in this/my scenario.