# Store List(s) in a database

Tags: django, django-models

My Users has phone contact LIST(s) - [3121234567,2121234567,6601234567]

Now, I want each user to be able to store as many LIST as possible. Each List must have a name(or description) attached to them under each USER account. Note: the number of LIST is dependent on Users needs. Example:

**Students**
[3121234567,2121234567,6601234567]

**Club Member**
[8101234567,8151234567,8171234567]

Now, how do I store it in a database.

**Django User Model**

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):

```
username = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True)    
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=24)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=128)
street = models.CharField(max_length=128)
city = models.CharField(max_length=128)
state = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATE_CHOICES, default=STATE)
zip_code = models.IntegerField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELD = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone', 'street', 'city', 'state']

objects = CustomUserManager()
```

Edit(Added):
I am not looking to create Student or ClubMember models. This name is use to identify the python phone contact list. PhoneAddress one can be labelled(named) as Student for one user but called "Conference Attendant" for another. Each user have different # of Lists.

PhoneAdress                 PhoneAdress2                PhoneAdress3
[3121234567,2121234567,6601234567]  [4121234567,3121234567,6601234567]  [7121234567,8121234567,9601234567]

Answer (score 3):

Lemme guess, you're coming from a NoSQL background where the database is a document in a JSON form?

If so, I am sorry, in a Relational Database, used by Django in the likes of PostgreSQL or MySQL, they call something Foreign Keys, and that is your way of storing multiple "Lists" related to a particular field.

If you want many users to store as many lists as possible, you're looking at something like this, roughly speaking:

```
class myUserModel(models.Model):
    # your arbitrary fields here
    # then you do something like this:

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class clubMember(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

With the above setup, you can add as many `Student` objects associated to the `myUserModel` class, so as the `clubMember`

However, if you wish to use PostgreSQL specifically, as your backend (perhaps as perpetual storage backend), you might find some sense in using Django's support for the [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield)

And ooh, you might need to extend the Django User Model to add any extra fields easily, unless you're willing to go down the road of a custom User Model.

More info:

- [Django ForeignKey](http://devdocs.io/django~1.9/ref/models/fields#django.db.models.ForeignKey)
- [This SO answer on 'OneToManyFields'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928692/how-to-express-a-one-to-many-relationship-in-django), similar to adding multiple items to a single field.

I hope the above helps

Comment: I am not looking to create Student or ClubMember models diretly. I want Users to be able to name their Phone contacts python List(s). The User can have as many as they wanted. I am Using PostGreSQL. I have not Used ArrayField. I will take a look at it. My model is a custom model hence the AbstractBaseUser.

Answer (score 0):

Create some models:

```
 class Club(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=True,null=True)
     date_open = models.DateField()

 class Institution(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=True,null=True)
     address = models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=True,null=True)
     type = models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=True,null=True) #university, college
```

Rather than using

```
 class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
     username = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True)    
     first_name = models.CharField(max_length=24)
     last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

use composition in the form of OneOnOneField

```
 class UserProfile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneOnOneField(User,blank=True,null=True)
     club_member = models.ManyToManyField(Club,blank=True, null=True)
     institutions = models.ManyToManyField(Institution,blank=True, null=True) # student in
```

Once you have this, you will be able to get and add as many institutions and clubs to the lists:

```
user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
club = Club.objects.get(id=club_id)
institution = Institution.objects.get(id=institution_id)

user.profile.clubs.add(club)
user.profile.institutions.add(institution)
```

So to verify if the user is a member of a club

```
club = user.proile.clubs.get(id=club_id)
```

and to verify the user is a student in an institution use

```
institution = user.profile.institutions.get(id=institution_id)
```