# Any alternatives for OneToMany or ManyToOne in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I have a **NOTIFICATION** and an **USER** app in Django.
The code goes something like :

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User , related_name = "notification"
    ....
    ....
```

and

```
class User(models.Model):
    notifications = models.OneToManyField(Notification , related_name = "user"
    ....
    ....
```

Now I know that **models.OneToManyField** doesn't exist in Django.
I get the fact that I can simply access the user from the notification instance of the model. But I suppose that would somehow slow my system because in production I would keep all the instances of Notification Model.
For example : I'm expecting around 500+ notifications per user once the system is in production for a significant amount of time.

I suppose, it would just be easier to access all the notifications of one user directly rather than sifting through the whole Notification Table to find notifications of a specific user.
I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928692/how-to-express-a-one-to-many-relationship-in-django) and the documentation to an extent and I'm not able to find a solution to my problem.

Also I'm not sure about the processing constraints of a processor to obtain all the Notifications from the whole Notification Table. I'm just assuming that it'll be somewhat slower.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`OneToManyField` doesn't exist in Django because it is just the reverse relationship of a `ForeignKey`.  So you don't need the `notifications` field on the `User` model here, just remove it.

Don't worry prematurely about performance of filtering on the notifications. Querying relations is what SQL was designed for, and that's what relational databases are good at doing.

Comment: I suppose trusting the filtering ability of my database engine is the most reliable solution at the moment. Thanks a ton!