# How to use oneToMany in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to add OneToMany field in django rest models. But Django is not giving an options for it. Can anyone suggest something similar to  java @OneToMany in Django framework

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to express a One-To-Many relationship in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928692/how-to-express-a-one-to-many-relationship-in-django)

Comment: " But Django is not giving an options for it. " => of course it is - how could an ORM skip something so obviously important ? It's spelled "ForeignKey".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `related_name` in ForeignKey field to achieve this. 
For example, you have the following models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name='books', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now, to access all books of an author the query will be `Author.books.all()`. Here, notice that `Author` model don't have `books` attribute. But in `author` ForeignKey field (which refers the `Author` model) of `Book` model has the related_name argument and its value is **books**. It means that books of an auhtor can be accessed from `Author` model. Django handles it nicely.

Also, you can use `select_related` for optimization (in this case you don't need to use `related_name` argument): `Book.objects.all().select_related('author')`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is working. I also found one more solution for this. We can use _set method for the same. In the above example to access all the books from an author we can do something like, author.book_set.all(). This will fetch all the books of a particular author.