# Django, connect one field with multiple models

Tags: django, many-to-many, field

I guess it is a "normal" problem. I want to connect model C with different Models A,B,..

```
Model A "buildings"
 - time_built
 - description
 - adress
 - architects[]=Model C
 - places

Model B "photos":
 - time_taken
 - title
 - architects[]=Model C
 - places

Model C "architects"
- title
- time_born
- website
- items[]=Model A+Model B
```

So items should be connected m:n to Model A or B for querying like "find architects by buildings in California". Model A and B can have multiple architects.

Is it possible to realize something like this in Django? I thought to use a Intermediate Model, but as I understood it does not help me too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Django has [Many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships).

In `Buildings`, put

```
    architects = models.ManyToManyField(Architect)
```

In `Photos`, put

```
    architects = models.ManyToManyField(Architect)
```

This will handle the relationship and by creation the migration file and running it, the DB tables will be created automatically (they should be 5).

Comment: I know this. But then I cannot query for architects who built buildings in Germany?

Comment: `Buildings.objects.filter(country_name='Germany').architects` will do that trick

Comment: Okay good to know, but then it does not search in the photos.places as well?

Comment: you can do the same thing in photos also. Pretty much anything you can do in plain SQL

Comment: I meant both at same time? But I guess I thought it from the wrong side of relation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok seems that there are two solutions:

- changing the layout of Models like Horatiu mentioned
- or what I found by random now and solved my problem what I was looking for: [GenericForeignKeys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) - [good example to explain](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/13/how-to-use-generic-relations.html) and [another question at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57564189/292975)