# Django model_name.item.add(item) add item to all records in the model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to achieve an order system for an e-commerce site with Django. I have Order Model and OrderItem Model as such

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    is_ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name

class Order(models.Model):
    ref_code = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    is_ordered = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    shipping = models.ForeignKey(AddressAndInfo, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    is_shipped = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
```

And My view function is such:

```
def checkout(request):
order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(
    owner=request.user).filter(is_ordered=False).all()

address = AddressAndInfo.objects.filter(user=request.user).get()
if(order_items.count() > 0):
    total = 0
    for item in OrderItem.objects.filter(owner=request.user).filter(is_ordered=False).all():
        if item.product.discounted_price > 0:
            total = total + item.product.discounted_price
        else:
            total = total + item.product.price
    order = Order.objects.create(
        owner = Profile.objects.get(user= request.user.id),
        shipping = address,
        price = total
    )
    new = Order.objects.get(items = None)
    print(new.ref_code)
    new.items.add(OrderItem.objects.get(owner=request.user, is_ordered=False))
    for item in order_items:
        item.is_ordered = True
        item.save()
    return redirect('dash')
else:
    messages.success(request, 'No item in Cart')
    return redirect('index')
```

Now the problem here is that when I try to add the second order from the user it adds order-item from the second order to all the existing order and. The result is that all the orders have same order-items. when ever I try to add order new order the order-item from the new order gets added to all existing orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made small changes to your code with some comments, hope this can help! :)

```
def checkout(request):
    order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(owner=request.user, is_ordered=False).all()

    address = AddressAndInfo.objects.filter(user=request.user).get()
    if(order_items.count() > 0):
        total = 0
        # Look, you can reuse order_items here instead of making another query to the database :)
        for item in order_items:
            if item.product.discounted_price > 0:
                total = total + item.product.discounted_price
            else:
                total = total + item.product.price

        order = Order.objects.create(
            owner = Profile.objects.get(user= request.user.id),
            shipping = address,
            price = total
        )
        # I think you were making a request to the database to get the Order that has no items, 
        # are you sure it will be always be just one order?
        # Anyway that wouldn't be necessary if you already have the instance of the recently created order in the 'order' variable above
        # new = Order.objects.get(items = None)
        print(order.ref_code)

        # Just one item is being added to the recently created Order here, 
        # and another query is being made to the database to get just one OrderItem with (owner=request.user, is_ordered=False)
        # maybe the is_ordered value of the item would be modified after this but I think it's safer to add the item after changing that value
        # order.items.add(OrderItem.objects.get(owner=request.user, is_ordered=False))
        for item in order_items:
            item.is_ordered = True            
            item.save()
            # Instead each item should be added inside this loop after each one is modified and saved
            order.items.add(item)
        return redirect('dash')
    else:
        messages.success(request, 'No item in Cart')
        return redirect('index')
```

Hope this can help! Anyway I'm not sure if you should use the `items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)` in the `Order` class, because you're saying that a same `ItemOrder` could belong to many `Orders` too? and I think what you want to do is that an `OrderItem` could only belong to just one Order right? maybe you can add an 'order' `ForeignKey` column to your `OrderItem` like this:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='items')
    is_ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(null = True)    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name


class Order(models.Model):
    ref_code = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    is_ordered = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    shipping = models.ForeignKey(AddressAndInfo, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    is_shipped = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
```

If you do this all that you have to change is to assign the order to your OrderItems in the final loop where you were updating them

```
for item in order_items:
    item.is_ordered = True 
    item.order = order          
    item.save()
```

Now you have OrderItems with just one Order in a database level :)

Comment: But i was trying to set only the order items in the cart to order model. My code used to add items in the cart to all existing records.

Comment: On the other this code just adds one order with order items. My app requires that user can order multiple item in one order

Comment: Have you tried the changes and it keeps giving errors with the first piece of code?

You get Orders with multiple OrderItems with the second piece of code that I added, maybe it seems that only add one order with order items, but that's the way you get One-To-Many relationships  between models.

Comment: You get Orders with multiple OrderItems with the second piece of code that I added, but that's the way you get One-To-Many relationships between models in Django, look at these links, they could help you to understand better what I was trying to do:

[link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928692/how-to-express-a-one-to-many-relationship-in-django)