# How do I reverse One To Many (ForeignKey) relation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have two models `File` and `Shared`, I want to add many `collaborators` to one `File` not one `collaborators` to many `File`, here are my models:

```
class File(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(primary_key=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_file_to)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    collaborators = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class Shared(models.Model):
    file = models.ForeignKey('File', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
```

Comment: Then you need to add the ForeignKey to your user model, even though in this type of situations the relationships are more of M2M type.

Comment: Your title is wrong, Many-to-one is ForeignKey not One-to-many, you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928692/how-to-express-a-one-to-many-relationship-in-django