# How to create OneToMany relationship?

Tags: django

I have model

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
```

How create model GroupMeeting witch can be connected with many meetings and one meeting can have only one GroupMeeting

```
class GroupMeeting ( models . Model ):
    meeting = models . ForeignKey ( Meeting , on_delete = models.SET_NULL 
    group_id = models . IntegerField () 
    name = models . CharField ( max_length = 255 )
```

in this case I have opposite situation
many `GroupMeeting`  have one `Meeting`

How to do it without changing `Meeting` class !!

Comment: Why is it a requirement to not change the `Meeting` class…?

Comment: Without changing `Meeting`, you can not.
Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928692/how-to-express-a-one-to-many-relationship-in-django

Answer (score 2):

You've got your ForeignKey the wrong way round. a ForeignKey is many-to-one so if you had

```
group_meeting = models.ForeignKey(GroupMeeting , on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

In Meeting class then you have your desired result